# Running multiple GAMM models using for loop or lapply

Tags: r, glm, gam

Can someone please help me with running multiple GAMM models in a for loop or lapply: I have a set of 10 response and 20 predictor variables in a large data frame arranged in columns.

I'd like to apply GAMM model for each predictor-response combination, and summarize their coefficients and significance tests in a table.

models<-gamm(AnimalCount ~ s(temperature), data=dat,family=poisson(link=log) , random=list(Province=~1) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one way to do this is to create a "matrix" list where the number of rows and columns corresponds to the number of responses (i) and predictors (j), respectively. Then you can store each model result in the cell[i, j]. Let me illustrate:

```
## make up some data
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0) 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=200,scale=2)
set.seed(1)
dat2 <- gamSim(1,n=200,scale=2)
names(dat2)[1:5] <- c("y1", paste0("x", 4:7))
d <- cbind(dat[, 1:5], dat2[, 1:5])
```

Now the made-up data has 2 responses (y, y1) and 8 predictors (x0 ~ x7). I think you can simplify the process by storing the responses and predictors in separate data frames:

```
d_resp <- d[ c("y", "y1")]
d_pred <- d[, !(colnames(d) %in% c("y", "y1"))]

## create a "matrix" list of dimensions i x j
results_m <- vector("list", length=ncol(d_resp)*ncol(d_pred))
dim(results_m) <- c(ncol(d_resp), ncol(d_pred))

for(i in 1:ncol(d_resp)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(d_pred)){
    results_m[i, j][[1]] <- gamm(d_resp[, i] ~ s(d_pred[, j]))
  }
}

# flatten the "matrix" list
results_l <- do.call("list", results_m)
```

You can use sapply/lapply to create a data frame to summarize coefficients, etc. Say, you want to extract fixed-effect intercepts and slopes and stored in a data frame.

```
data.frame(t(sapply(results_l, function(l) l$lme$coef$fixed)))
```

Comment: This works - runs like magic. I am now struggling to include into the summary table of the results, the gam summary components..i.e. names of x and y variables (i.e.formula components), z/t/F values, pvalues, aic, bic, deviance. Is it possible to include all these in this summary table? I would also like to save plots the individual models - ideally 6 panels per page.

Comment: I suggest you use `str`, with or without `summary`, to locate what you are looking for. Then you can combine them with `sapply` to extract it from all models. For example, `sapply(results_l, function(l) summary(l$gam)$p.table[, 4])` extracts all p-values from the gam models. After extracting everything you want, you can combine them as a data frame. As for plots, you can use `par(mfrow=c(3, 2)); lapply(results_l, function(l) plot(l$gam))` to plot 6 gam models per page.

Comment: only thing is, i'd like to save the plots to a file plus from the plots i cant tell what variable x and y axis is..

Comment: The simplest ways to do are the following: if you use RStudio, you can export each plot as a format of your choice. Also, you can supply x- and y-axis labels manually, instead of using `lapply()`, while keeping `par(mfrow=c(3,2))`.

Comment: There is >500 plots, assigning xy labels manually will take forever. It would also be great of I can have the variable names on the data frame created above..

Comment: @MasatoNakazawa is there a way to use this same process, but for trying different combinations of multiple explanatory variables? Say for example, on top of a temperature variable, we also had a salinity and precipitation variable, and we wanted to test gams covered all possible combinations? such as one for each individual explanatory variable as demonstrated here, but also gams that tested for example, temperature + precipitation, or temperature + salinity, or temperature+precipitation+salinity in the model?